# Magento 2 graphql authentication

Tags: graphql

I have created a custom graphql APIs ,
I want to restrict these APIS for unwanted use ,
How can I restrict access to API'S

Any help is appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Use customer token or any header value or custom header value.

Comment: have u got solution?please help me

Answer (score 0):

I check resources like this in my resolver class. You can assign certain permissions/resources for api integrations that you create in the Magento admin. They'll get an auth code/codes which are sent in headers, and that auth code has permissions to certain acl resources.

```
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface; 

//...create with di in construct...

//an example you could use in your methods
if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('--RESOURCE HERE--')) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(__('Forbidden'), 0, 403);
}
```